# Google Cloud Run runs over and over again in error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I'm using Cloud Run that is getting triggered by a pubsub message.
But when this Cloud Run code gets an error it does re-run the application over and over again.
This seems unnecessary now when testing because I see the error in the log and doesn't need the code to re-run.

Where can I turn this off?
I'm using Node JS.

Comment: Cloud Run runs in response to an HTTP request or an event. If PubSub is sending an event to Cloud Run and Cloud Run fails, PubSub will retry. To stop this, purge/delete/process the messages in PubSub. The CLI `gcloud` will help you interact with PubSub: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub

Comment: Could you improve your question? I recommend you take a look at this document too -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't know how to improve the question sorry! There is nothing "wrong" with the code - It's only about Google Cloud and how it functions with acking messages in pubsub.

But I fixed it short term by sending 200 status in the catch err block.

Comment: @JohiOakey could you share as answer how you solved this issue? The information could help other members of the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can purge your PubSub push subscription, or delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved it short term by enclosing the whole code block by a try/catch and then always be sure to a throw err to catch the error.

After that instead of returning a 400 status in the catch block I returned 200 and the pubsub message got ack:ed that everything was working (Even if it did not).